# Prestashop : is there any hook to update the shipping price?

Tags: php, module, prestashop

PRESTASHOP : I'm working on a prestashoo module and I need to make the shipping list dynamic

Is there any hook to update the shipping price ?

Comment: after installing module, you can do it from admin panel

Comment: no, in the admin panel the list of shipping price is fix, in my case i need to make the shipping price dynamic

Comment: ok which shipping module you are using?

Comment: im using a custom one, which im currently developing

Comment: @user2861455 Have you tryed with my solution? If you have any question feel free to ask ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and the right hook is extraCarrier.
It adds a new carrier to the shop and is fully configurable.

See this link for an example of usage:
https://github.com/uab-balticode/dpd-shipping-module-prestashop-lt/blob/53679ab5935965d95950fb3dc99a18c0c995697d/balticode_dpd_courier/balticode_dpd_courier.php

Or even better you can copy from official carriers modules, like the TNT Express one:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/tntcarrier/blob/675d9e8866f675968cc46eaec73d4202278d90a1/tntcarrier.php

From the source of this modules you must look for `$this->registerHook('extraCarrier')` in install function to regiser your hook (remember to reinstall your module after the hook insertion in your code)
and for the function definition of `public function hookextraCarrier($params)` where all the magic happens
Also note how the class of the module must extend `CarrierModule`:

`class TntCarrier extends CarrierModule`

You can also read the official prestashop documentation about the argument:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+carrier+module

Comment: i need to set the shipping price in my module, do you have any idea how to do this ?

Comment: You need to create a new carrier in your module as I suggested above

Comment: the alternative is to modify your current carrier price by editing his module, remember that the shipping price is set in the `hookextraCarrier($params)` function